# How do I select(mouse selection) a specific text inside a html element? selenium C# javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In the below HTML element I want to select a specified text. I need do the operation even inside the element. Not on the element level.

In the below given div there are 4 lines. I need help to create a function that select a specific text inside the html element.
For example if i pass "dummy test data" to the function , it should mouse select the specific string.

```
<div data-fid="0" id="tbobjectContent-div1">
Sheet1 SCS OPTION DATA.
This is a dummy test data. Please select this sentence.
Selection has to be mouse select.
Please do it selenium C# combination        
</div>
```

Comment: The closest solution I am right now is at.  And i am not looking for solutions in this direction.
~~~

IWebElement content = dri.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='tbobjectContent-div1']"));
Actions builder = new Actions(dri);              builder.MoveToElement(content,10,20).ClickAndHold().MoveByOffset(0,60).Release().Perform();
~~~

Comment: Any one out there to help on this issue?. HELP!!